# Can someone give me the resolution procedure for 2 SAT, which is O (nˆ2)

Tags: algorithms, satisfiability, 2-sat

According to Wikipedia, Even, S .; Itai, A .; Shamir, A. cited it in "On the complexity of time table and multi-commodity flow problems".

The paper can be found here: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/wwwb/cgi-bin/tr-get.cgi/1975/CS/CS0059.pdf

EDIT: Reference [5] of the above paper can be found here:
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2310460

Comment: The paper is 27 pages long. Can you point to the exact location where this is mentioned, or copy the relevant text?

Comment: Several algorithms are described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability#Algorithms), including one attributed to your paper.

Comment: This is mentioned on page 14

Comment: The paper gives the appropriate references on page 14.

Comment: Ok, I leave the question standing here and try to understand how an algorithm with quantifiers performs the resolution step in time complexity n square.

Comment: What do you mean "algorithm with quantifiers"?

Comment: The work of Davis and Putnam "A Computing Procedure for Quantification Theory" describes an algorithm with quantifiers.

Comment: I searched for "resolution solver for 2sat" and found this link to [Krom's algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51302/how-to-do-last-step-of-kroms-algorithm-for-solving-2sat-problems). There are much better 2SAT solvers.